# List of list to a comma separated list in Java

Tags: list, arraylist, collections, java-8

I have a list as `List<List<String>> next = iterator.next();` In this list data will be like

```
[[a, b, c], [a, b]]
[[a, b, c], [a]]
[[a, b], [a]]
```

When I convert into a list as,

```
List<String> collect = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it returns a list like,

```
[a, b, c, a, b]
[a, b, c, a]
[a, b, a]
```

Is there a possible way to create a new `List<String>` using `List<List<String>>` as same as,

```
[[a, b, c], [a, b]]
[[a, b, c], [a]]
[[a, b], [a]]
```

Comment: But your data currently looks more like a `List<List<List<String>>>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to intend is just use `List.toString` as:

```
List<String> collect = list.stream()
        .map(Object::toString) // default string representation for the inner list
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is what I exactly wanted. Wasted over 16 hours already. Thanks you so much